# How can I make a function work for both string and wstring?

Tags: c++, string, unicode, wstring

If I want a function like the following to work on `basic_string<char>` and `basic_string<wchar>` what should I do?
Note that it has to change `wchar_t` in the unordered map.

The function needs to accept also `wchar_t` array to support passing the argument as a literal.

```
bool isUnique(wstring s)
{
    if (s.size() <= 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    unordered_map<wchar_t, bool> charSeen;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
    {
        if (!charSeen[s[i]])
        {
            charSeen[s[i]] = true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    cout << isUnique(L"فعه");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you already consider templatetizing the function?

Comment: Use `charT` in `template<class charT>bool isUnique(std::basic_string<charT> s)`

Comment: `std::string` and `std::wstring` are just `typedef`s for `std::basic_string<char>` and `std::basic_string<wchar_t>`, respectively.

Comment: That wouldn't work for the example I gave in main since the input is a wchar_t array and the compiler doesn't let that go.

Comment: I guess you're referring to [this problem](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc21200d9d9bbfb8)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a helper function take a character pointer and delegate to the main function passing a `std::basic_string`:

```
template<class charT>
bool isUnique(charT const* p)
{
    return isUnique(std::basic_string<charT>(p));
}
```

Then change your main `isUnique` function to take a `std::basic_string` templated on its character type:

```
template <typename charT>
bool isUnique(std::basic_string<charT>);
```